# Automated Auhorization Response

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

Can someone please let me know how set an automated response when someone register on my site?

At the moment, if someone registers on my site, they get an automated message saying the following:

> Thank you for registering at Keyloop elabs. Your account is created and must be verified before you can use it.
>   To verify the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser:
>    http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/settings/your-profile?task=registration.activate&token=321708980e005c2d7e831a89463c95c2
>
> After verification an administrator will be notified to activate your account. You'll receive a confirmation when it's done.
>   Once that account has been activated you may login to http://www.keylooplabs.com/ using the following username and password:

I would like to configure Joomla to send an automated response when they click on the link to verify their account.

Can someone show me how?

Kind regards

Carlton

Answer (score 1):

As per official Joomla documentation on [Components Users Configuration](https://docs.joomla.org/Help34:Components_Users_Configuration), it states under Component Settings | New User Account Activation that there are three options:

- None. User account will be active immediately with no action
  required.
- Self. User will receive an email with an activation link.
  The account will be activated when the user clicks the activation
  link.
- Admin. User will receive an email with an activation link.
  When the user clicks this link, the Site Admin will be notified via
  email and the Site Admin needs to activate the user's account.

It seems you should set option `Self`.